# Is $e^{\sin z}$ an analytic function?

Tags: complex-analysis, cauchy-riemann-equations

Here is my work.

$$
e^{\sin z}
= e^{\sin(x+iy)}
= e^{\sin x \cos(iy) + \cos x \sin(iy) }
= e^{\sin x \cosh y + i\cos x \sinh y}
$$

So, $u = e^{\sin x \cosh y}$ and $v = e^{\cos x \sinh y}$. Then,

$$
\frac{\partial u}{\partial x} = \cos x \, e^{\sin x \cosh y} 
\qquad\text{and}\qquad
\frac{\partial v}{\partial y} = \cosh y \, e^{\cos x \sinh y}.
$$

So, not analytic because $\frac{\partial u}{\partial x} \neq \frac{\partial v}{\partial y}$ thus not satisfying Cauchy Riemann equations.

Is it correct?

Comment: Have you proven the chain rule for holomorphic funtions?

Comment: Welcome to math.SE. Please consider using MathJax. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [here](/help/notation), [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: All elementary functions are analytic almost everywhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it is not correct. We have indeed$$e^{\sin(x+yi)}=e^{\sin(x)\cosh(y)+\cos(x)\sinh(y)i},$$but this, in turn, is equal to$$e^{\sin(x)\cosh(y)}\left(\cos\bigl(\cos(x)\sinh(y)\bigr)+\sin\bigl(\cos(x)\sinh(y)\bigr)i\right).$$So$$u(x,y)=e^{\sin(x)\cosh(y)}\cos\bigl(\cos(x)\sinh(y)\bigr)$$and$$v(x,y)=e^{\sin(x)\cosh(y)}\sin\bigl(\cos(x)\sinh(y)\bigr).$$Anyway, $\exp\circ\sin$ is analytic because it is the composition of two analytic functions.

Comment: I figured  that I am carrying out partial derivatives incorrectly .

Comment: Partial derivative of u w.r.t x will be cosxcoshye^sinxcoshy.   And that of v w.r.t y will be the same thus satisfying CR equations

Comment: There are *two* Cauchy-Riemann equations. But, yes, every point of $\Bbb R^2$ is a solution of each of them.

Comment: Yes I know there are two . I just showed the particular mistake I was making while carrying out the partial derivatives i.e.not putting the whole constant exponential term before e.

Answer (score 0):

w= u+iv

= e^sin z

= e^sin(x+iy)

= e^[sinx cos(iy)+ cosx sin(iy)]

(Since sin(a+b) = sina cosb+ cosa sinb)

Change this to a hyperbolic function

= e^[sinx coshy + cosx isinhy]

(since cos(iy)= coshy ; sin(iy)= isinhy)

= e^[sinx coshy]. e^[i cosx sinhy]

(since e^(a+b) = e^a . e^b)

= e^[sinx coshy] [cos(cosx sinhy) + i sin(cosx sinhy)]

(since e^ia = cosa + isina)

=  e^[sinx coshy]. cos(cosx sinhy) +i e^[sinx coshy]. sin(cosx sinhy)

u= e^[sinx coshy]. cos(cosx sinhy)

v= e^[sinx coshy]. sin(cosx sinhy)

∂u/∂x = e^[sinx coshy] [-sin(cosx sinhy) . (-sinx sinhy)]+ cos(cosx sinhy) [ e^[sinx coshy] . cosx coshy]

**∂u/∂x =**  **e^[sinx coshy] {sinx sinhy sin(cosx sinhy) +  cosx coshy cos(cosx sinhy)}**

(by using the differential formula uv'+vu')

∂v/∂y= e^[sinx coshy] cos(cosx sinhy). cosx coshy + sin(cosx sinhy). e^[sinx coshy] . sinx sinhy

**∂v/∂y=  e^[sinx coshy] {sinx sinhy sin(cosx sinhy) + cosx coshy cos(cosx sinhy)}**

therefore **∂u/∂x = ∂v/∂y**

∂u/∂y= e^[sinx coshy] [-sin(cosx sinhy) . cosx coshy] + cos(cosx sinhy). e^[sinx coshy]. sinx sinhy

**∂u/∂y= e^[sinx coshy] {-cosx coshy sin(cosx sinhy) + sinx sinhy cos(cosx sinhy)}**

∂v/∂x= e^[sinx coshy] cos(cosx sinhy). (-sinx sinhy) + sin(cosx sinhy) e^[sinx coshy]. cosx coshy

∂v/∂x=e^[sinx coshy] {cosx coshy sin(cosx sinhy) - sinx sinhy cos(cosx sinhy)}

**-∂v/∂x=e^[sinx coshy] {-cosx coshy sin(cosx sinhy) + sinx sinhy cos(cosx sinhy)}**

therefore **∂u/∂y=-∂v/∂x**

Cauchy Riemann equations are satisfied and hence the function e^sinz is an analytic function

(Note : differential formulae used here are, ∂sinx/∂x = cosx ; ∂cosx/∂x=-sinx ; ∂sinhx/∂x = coshx; ∂coshx/∂x = sinhx)

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/users/446262/jos%c3%a9-carlos-santos    . thank you sir i could able to solve the problem further with your post

Comment: This is difficult to read. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).